# Write blank line to file in C

Tags: c

I used the write function to write some stuff into a file. now i want to insert a blank link into the file before the next write function, do anyone know how to do that?

```
Write(logs,log,strlen(log));
```

is my first write, so now is the new line going to be:

```
Write(logs,'/n',strlen(log));
```

or should I create a new `char[3] = '/n';`?

Comment: It would depend on what the `Write()` function does.  (the third parameter could mean how many characters to write but that's a guess at best)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you mean the POSIX `write()` function, something like this should work:

```
write(logs,"\n",1);
```

Note that `"\n"` is a 1 character string - you may want `"\r\n"` depending on if you need a carriage return and a new line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that you need to address is that the newline character is represented by backslash-n (`'\n'` or `"\n"`) and not slash-n.

When you write `'/n'`, you should be getting a compiler warning about a multi-character character constant which is a non-portable piece of C.

Obviously, you could create a variable to hold the newline, but there's really no need; the string literal will be be fine.  If you do, the correct notation would be:

```
const char newline[] = "\n";
```

You could write:

```
const char rather_odd[3] = { '/n' };
```

but...the braces are necessary, and the first character has a compiler-dependent value, and the other two characters are NUL `'\0'`.  This uses more than the minimum necessary space, too; the `newline` variable is a 2-byte array.

With your non-standard `Write()` function, the correct syntax is probably:

```
Write(logs, "\n", 1);
```

This emits a single newline; if the previous string (the one in `log`) was not itself terminated by a newline, you do not have a blank line in the file; you would have to write a second newline.  You might even want to test that:

```
size_t len = strlen(log);
Write(logs, log, len);
len = (log[len-1] == '\n') ? 1 : 2;
Write(logs, "\n\n", len);
```

Note, too, that GCC will warn you about a global variable called `log` (because the C standard reserves the name).  Local variables are OK.

```
$ cat x.c
int x = '/n';
int log = 2;
$ gcc -c x.c
x.c:1:9: warning: multi-character character constant
x.c:2:5: warning: built-in function ‘log’ declared as non-function
$
```

I came across this problem recently while resurrecting some code last modified about 20 years ago.

(Testing with GCC 4.5.2 on MacOS X 10.6.6.)

Answer (score 0):

> I know this post is pretty old but, I'am creating a log file and when
>   I attempt to write a "\n" it won't write it....:
>
> ```
> write(fd,"\n\n==== NEW CLIENT ====\n\n",24);
> ```
>
> The output in the file is:
>
> ```
> ==== NEW CLIENT ====
> ```
>
> Without any blank line...any idea ? even if I put:
>
> ```
> write(fd,"\n",1);
> ```
>
> nothing to do... :/

I got it...i was compiling the program in linux and checking the log file in windows, if I open the log file in linux it's ok...